# How can i add button to a column in a ngx-datatable in Angular 8?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular8, ngx-datatable

This HTML code is not working for me.

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="Option" prop="option" [draggable]="false" [resizeable]="false 
         [width]="250">
      <span>
        <button class="optionButton" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data- 
        target="#addOption">Reserve Product</button>
      </span>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```

Comment: See this source [code](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/src/app/templates/template-dom.component.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the button within `<ng-template>`

Try like this:

```
<ngx-datatable-column name="Option" prop="option" [draggable]="false" [resizeable]="false 
     [width]="250">
    <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-value="value">
        <span>
            <button class="optionButton" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data- 
    target="#addOption">Reserve Product</button>
         </span>
    </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-column>
```